# iTunes always asks me whether to back up apps from my iPad and iPhone

Tags: itunes

Every time I connect my iPad or iPhone to my Mac, iTunes gives me a prompt like this:

[image: “There are apps on your iPad which are not in your iTunes library. Would you like to back up these apps from your iPad? These apps will not be installed on a device when you restore unless they are in your iTunes library.”]

I’ve been clicking “Back Up Apps” for both devices, and yet I get the same prompt every time I connect. How can I stop iTunes from asking me every time? (I don’t really care whether it backs up my apps or not.)

Comment: That didn't work. Have have all 4 options set to automatic download already.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4539) page by Apple

You can change this in the iTunes settings, called **Automatic Downloads**.
Check the box, as the image displays and the applications should download instead of ask for a backup.

If you cannot click the checkboxes, you have sign in to the iTunes Store with your Apple ID.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the right answer is, but the above solution does not solve the problem.